# awk printing lines in different order to original file

Tags: awk, output

I have a csv file with 6 columns. Col3 is an ID, and Col4 is a count. 
I want to get print Col3, and then convert the Col4 to a frequency.

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6
9,19,9,7,9,6
10,132,10,131,10,65
10.3,0,10.3,0,10.3,1
11,128,11,182,11,82
```

My command

```
awk -F"," '{if (NR!=1) f[$3] = $4; SUM += $4} END { for (i in f) { print i, f[i]/SUM } }' myfile.csv > myoutfile.txt
```

Unexpectedly, its printing the output lines in the wrong order - 10.3 comes before 10.
Is there a way to fix this

```
9,0.021875
10.3,0
10,0.409375
11,0.56875
```

Comment: The `in` operator parses the array in some internally-defined order, not guaranteed to be the order in which the array was populated, nor alphabetical, nor any other that you might expect. If you want to get the output in a specific order you must write the code to implement that order. In GNU awk you can set values in PROCINFO, see the man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==1{next}NR==FNR{sum+=$4;next}{print $3,(sum>0?$4/sum:0)}' file file
9,0.021875
10,0.409375
10.3,0
11,0.56875
```

You do two passes to the file. For both passes we do a check that if it is the first line, we skip it by doing `FNR==1{next}`. In the first pass, you create a variable `sum` and keep adding column 4 value to it. In the second pass we just print the 3rd column along with frequency (4th column / sum).

Notice that I have used `file file` due to two passes. You can use brace expansion and do `file{,}`

Comment: +1 but you might want to move the `FNR>1` test so it applies to the first pass too, otherwise if the 4th col header started with a number (e.g. `4Col` instead of `Col4`) then that too would be included in the `sum` calculation. That's not real likely to happen of course but it's trivial to guard against with a leading `FNR==1{next}`.